# increment between (inclusive) 1 and 10 with 100 total values

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, linear-programming

so I want to find the increment value such that I can get 100 total numbers, between(including) 1 and 10.

So, for a more simple example if I want to get 10 total numbers, between(including) 1 and 10, I can do (10-1)/(10-1) = 0.1.

However, I a cannot come up with a formula to do such.

Comment: $(10-1)/(10-1) = 1 \neq 0.1$

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ values between $a$ and $b$ inclusive of $a$ and $b$, the increment between values is$$i = \frac{b-a}{n-1}$$

(Corrected from original)

It follows directly from the $k$-th value being $a+(k-1)i$.  The final value is $a+(n-1)i = b$.

Comment: that does not work, so lets take the case where b is 10, a is 1, and n is 100.        i = 0.1 in that case, and there will only be a total of 91 values, instead of 100 between 1 and 100 inclusive

Comment: Sorry, caffeine hadn't quite kicked in.  Put the 1 in the wrong place with the wrong sign.$$i = \frac{b-a}{n-1}$$